# is it save to remove something in git local repository and commit

Tags: git, large-files

Basically, I am using git lfs system. In my folder1/ I have tons of local files (some of them are in the remote repository also) which I have not committed. Now, I want to clean up some space and I kind of decided to delete the whole folder1, but i do not want to affect the remote git repo. However, I am still a contributer to the git repo.

Is it safe to just,

```
rm -r folder1/
```

and git commit my other changes later?

```
git commit folder2/
```

Thank you.

**Edit: one final question:**

I have one more question, suppose after, I rm -r folder1/, I want to restore the contents of folder1/ (for those in the repository), should i just do git checkout folder1/

Comment: Yes; just make sure not to stage the removal.

Comment: could you tell me the command for staging the removal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Should be fine.

I believe this GIT simplification might be useful when doing such tasks:

[image]

Source [here](http://gitready.com/beginner/2009/01/21/pushing-and-pulling.html)

Just as measure of precaution make diff before pulling/pushing.

Comment: I have one more question, suppose after, I rm -r  folder1/, I want to restore the contents of folder1/ (for those in the repository), should i just do git checkout folder1/

Comment: Checkout should do that. If you want to add more specific rules on what to sync you might want to check [this](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) out.